# Strange PostgreSQL behaviour on service start

Tags: postgresql, centos

Centos 8.3, postgresql 12 (i tried even 10, same thing).

I have set
the permission of the data directory to `postgres:postgres`. If I start
the service from `systemctl`, it gives me the error message

> "creation of lock file "postmaster.pid" failed: Permission denied".

If I copy the command from `postgresql.service` which is `postmaster -D /data/pgdata` and I run from the console as `postgres` user, it works, and the `postmaster.pid`file is correctly created.

I have no ideas, because it's not a permission problem...

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the user that fails on startup a member of the `postgres` group? If not, make them one and try!

Comment: in the postgresql.service is correctly written postgres as user and postgres as group

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i understood.

It was a "problem" of selinux.

I changed the data directory, and selinux "didn't know" it, so i

chcon -R -t postgresql_db_t /data/pgdata

restorecon -RFv /data/pgdata.